# NodeJS: Reading JSON array from a web request

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js

This might be a n00b question, but I am trying to understand nodeJS code that is given to me which supposedly works in production. This is an API which I want to make use of, but stuck as it fails to understand the JSON string that comes in the request.

```
var server = {};
server.create = function _create(req) {
    //req= JSON.parse(req);
    req.forEach(function (origReq) {
        console.log(origReq);
    });
}

var req = "[{\"id\":\"1\"},{\"id\":\"2\"}]";
server.create(req);
```

Running this, I get this error because "req" is not identified as a JS object/array and the .forEach is not available on a string, which it is:

**

> TypeError: undefined is not a function

**

Understandably, if the "Commented" line of code is uncommented, the string is parsed to proper JS array and it works Ok.

With the request having a proper content-type of "application/json", is it not understood/parsed by default? **how possibly the code without the parse statement could work** (parse statement was introduced by me and does not exist in the original code part of a working API). Probably the node module (server module as it is usually called) should handle this from the incoming header info?

My apologies if I am missing something fundamental and thanks for all your inputs.

Comment: Perhaps someone was using Express with JSON parsing middleware and passed `req.body` to `server.create()`? Who knows. The only way it could have possibly worked before is if it was passed an already parsed array.

Comment: You should *not* call a JavaScript object/array a "JSON object/array". That's just confusing when actually talking about JSON as well.

Comment: @mscdex: Thanks and I get your point. It could no way be an already parsed array from the browser request and has to be parsed before being processed. I did not see Express or any middleware being used. However, I will be investigating more on this for sure

Answer (score 1):

content-type `"application/json"` will not be retrieved as a JavaScript object. You are retrieving plain text (string). Just like `"text/HTML"` or `"text/plain"` content-types.

calling `JSON.parse(req)` is key as it will parse this string into a JavaScript object.

**EDIT:**

Some frameworks (like Angular.js) will read the response's content-type and parse the response into a JavaScript Object for you. However the "request" Node Module (that you might be using) will not parse the response for you. You must do it yourself.